# Including modules in IronPython for .Net

Tags: python, c#-4.0, ironpython

I'm using IronPython 2.7.7 for .Net to run some python code (Installed using NuGet in an MVC project).

I got a simple test case to work quite easily, but when I went to include the actual python code I want to call I ran into problems with missing modules.

> No module named Crypto.Cipher    Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module named Crypto.Cipher

These are the modules / libraries that the python script has at the beginning, I can see in visual studio that it's complaining about missing `Crypto.Cipter` and `random`.

```
from datetime import datetime
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import time
import random
import socket
```

This is the .Net code that I'm calling the Python code with.

```
var basePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
var realPath = Path.Combine(basePath, @"Python/PythonThingy.py");

var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic pyThing = ipy.UseFile(realPath);
var items = pyThing.discover(timeout: 5);
```

I am not allowed to install Python on the production server, so I'm hoping I can include these libraries in some way and avoid rewriting a quite huge set of functions. Any tips on how to do this?

P.S. If not apparent from post, I know very little about python.

Comment: I have the same problem, (also new in python) and trying to work using c#, it's seems to me that the Lib in IronPython 2.7 is missing many of the modules, If you copy the missing module into the Lib folder of IronPython, it will continue asking you for other module, so either the installation is not full, or something else, I also need an advice here...